# Torrent contain all Hashes for each piece of file..?

Tags: p2p, bittorrent, utorrent, monotorrent

Torrent File contain all hashID for each piece or not..?
Means if content (data to be download) contain 1000 pieces then torrent file hold hashID for each piece or  not?

If it contain all the hashID then How I get these HashID from torrent file
and If not what technique should I use to get these HashID's.

Answer (score 1):

The .torrent file contain the SHA-1 hash of each piece in the file(s).

To access these hashes, decode the file (it's [bencoded](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html#bencoding)). In the dictionary under the key "info" there is a key called "pieces" which is a string. This string contains all piece hashes concatenated. Each has is 20 bytes long.